# setting up triple integral in spherical coordinates of a non-centered sphere

Tags: calculus, spherical-coordinates

I am having trouble setting up the region of integration for a sphere centered at (0,0,1) with a radius of 1 using spherical coordinates. I know the upper bound for rho is 2cos(phi) but I cant figure out the lower bound.

P.S. I know there is a way to change to make (0,0,1) the new origin but I know that is not what I am supposed to do for this problem so would prefer to know some other way especially since the equation I am integrating is $\sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254777/spherical-coordinates-for-sphere-with-centre-neq-0.  I think that answer will help.

Comment: it helped some but I am still struggling to understand and picture the bounds and how they are changed by the shifted sphere. so $\theta$ would still be from 0 to 2pi? and phi from 0 to pi?