# Spherical coordinates for sphere with arbitrary centre and radius

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The parametric equation of a sphere with radius $1$ and centre $(1,0,0)$ is provided in the discussion [Spherical coordinates for sphere with centre $\neq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254777/spherical-coordinates-for-sphere-with-centre-neq-0/1254963#1254963)

I would like to know the parametric equation of a sphere for an arbitrary value of radius and centre coordinates.

Comment: You might try working through the linked computation using an arbitrary center and/or radius yourself.